# What can be considered as "Home ties" for a UK Standard Visitor visa (PLAB)?

Tags: visas, uk, indian-citizens

I am an Indian national who recently cleared his PLAB1 examination and has booked to sit PLAB2 in UK (which can be given only in UK). Before applying for a visa, I would like to know about the how one can prove home ties. Of course, I have read about the Family, Job, Property being used as ties but...

I haven't worked since my graduation (two years now) as I wasted a lot of precious time on USMLE. After that IELTS and then PLAB1. So can't show job as tie.

I don't have any property in my name but my father does have residential plots and agricultural lands worth a few crores on his name.

Does an affidavit that I am his only son and heir to all that bla bla bla, serve the purpose?

I do have few life insurance policies in my name.

Can they be used as an indicator of some kind of active Indian society member thingy?

I am unmarried but do intend to show my parents as family ties.

I did my medical studies in China (6-7 years). I have also traveled to a few countries like Russia, Thailand, Philippines, HK, Macau etc etc (though not a single Western country).

Can that be used in my favour in home ties that I have always obeyed country's laws and returned to India upon completion of the purpose of the trip?

Comment: The entry clearance officer who processes your visa application will look for the reasons why you would return to India instead of remaining in the UK where you might be tempted to work and overstay. This is what is meant by ties to your home. What reasons do you have for returning to India? And can you document them?

Comment: What's your purpose for sitting the PLAB? I'm not familiar with the details but it seems to be an examination required for doctors to practice medicine in the UK. Wouldn't they be rightly suspicious that you *would* intend to stay? Otherwise, if you intend to leave, why sit the examination?

Comment: Purpose of sitting the PLAB is solely to be registered General Meical council which kinda makes u eligible to work as physician is many commonwealth countries like australia, SA etc and even in india is highly deemed on good positions.  again, as almost everyone clearing this exam get a job offered in NHS after which they need to return to their home country and apply for Tier 2 visa and re-enter Uk. so, purpose of this visa still remains the same, to sit in PLAB 2 and get GMC registration

Comment: Maybe you could use this to your advantage, although I don't know how effective it would be. Talk about your career plans, that you invested so long in medical school and that you're going to all this trouble to further your career. Somebody in your position would not be likely to overstay illegally, because it would be wasting all that time in medical school. But I'm not an expert. Maybe it would be helpful to speak to a solicitor in the UK about this.

Comment: No experience personally, but it seems like your level of qualification would be a good indicator that you won't break the rules. There'd be little incentive for you to overstay and work illegally (presumably that wouldn't be possible in the medical field so you'd take a big pay cut). Plus you'd likely have a chance at immigrating legally if you wanted to after returning from sitting the exam.

Comment: @CarlfromBusbud It's a worthy assumption, but in reality PLAB sitters are horrendous abusers (and I mean appalling), hence high risk, hence the OP's question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Home ties cannot be conjured out of thin air. They either exist or, as seems to be the case for you, they do not. A magical set of words for the application form is wishful thinking.

> Does an affidavit that I am his only son and heir to all that bla bla bla, serve the purpose?

Not really. First of all if in your father's name there is already (I take it) somebody local to manage the property – your presence is not necessary. Even if you were to inherit it tomorrow you might sell it at the earliest opportunity so it would not demand your attention on site.  Affidavits hold no weight at all and they routinely discount and ignore them. If your father has a history of supporting you, then emphasis this part of your application.

> Can they be used as an indicator of some kind of active Indian society member thingy?

No, life insurance policies prove nothing. Including them shows the ECO that you did not read the guidance.

> I am unmarried but do intend to show my parents as family ties.

That won't help much either – they seem to have managed without you during your medical studies ("China (6-7 years)").

> I have also traveled to a few countries like Russia, Thailand, Philippines, HK, Macau etc etc (though not a single Western country).

Crossing borders and then behaving yourself is a good sign. A history of travel performance is a *huge* benefit, the benefit grows exponentially if the history shows travel to the affluent Commonwealth or the EEA or North America.

Otherwise what you are looking for is some compelling reason or reasons why it is imperative you must return to India after sitting PLAB2. What these might be, if they exist, depend upon your specific circumstances and we don't know enough about those to extract from them what you yourself seem unable to.

You have already considered all the most common: Family, Job, Property, marriage and Indian society thingy. Maybe there just is nothing exerting a pull to return you to India. Not to say any application you make is sure to fail, but it does seem likely to reduce your chances of being granted a visa. Perhaps defer applying until you do have a job - even perhaps by then be married, or at least have been in India long enough to have set down roots there as an adult.