# Are tourist visas given to people with only family ties?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, tourist-visas, ireland

I am an Indian citizen. I plan to visit Ireland as a tourist this July, and so I am applying for a short term stay type C visa. From the INIS website (http://www.inis.gov.ie/en/INIS/Pages/Visit%20Tourist), I need to prove ties to India in the form of 1) a job, 2) education and 3) family.

I have finished my college education and I do not have a job waiting when I return (my aim is to take a gap year). I do, however, have family - my father, who is elderly (but not retired), and who was ill earlier this year. Have other Indians managed to get an Irish tourist visa using only family ties?

Comment: It is an opinion based question. Yes, you have to prove strong ties with your home country.

Comment: I do not think this is opinion-based. I am not asking if I will be able to get a visa - I am asking if other Indians have been able to procure an Irish tourist visa, solely using family ties.

Comment: Sounds to me like an experiences question, not an opinion question.  People can only say what works or doesn't; no opinion is given.

Comment: Travel history, especially to other countries that require visas, also gives you credibility because it shows that you've previously travelled and returned as you should have and abided by the rules of your visa/travel permission.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prove that you have significant ties in your home country](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/103826/how-to-prove-that-you-have-significant-ties-with-family-in-your-home-country) and [What can be considered as “Home ties”](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/83482/what-can-be-considered-as-home-ties-for-a-uk-standard-visitor-visa-plab) and [Proving ties to your home country a non-employed visa national?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/51589/proving-ties-to-your-home-country-when-applying-for-a-schengen-visa-as-a-non-emp)